# Auto Increment id for collection - Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to add a id auto increment in Mongo like MySQL does.

I use the [Mongoose Auto Increment Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) and this works fine.

My problem is that I was not able to place that ID in the documents already created after implementing the library

In this I created a Query to made this before add that library

```
db.clients.updateMany({},{$set:{id:0}})
```

This add the 'id' field in all documents whit 0 as value.

Now I want to add the correct id to all documents, but this query add the same id to all documents.

```
for(var i=0; i<db.clients.count(); i++){
    db.clients.update({},{$set:{id:i}})
}
```

Someone have any idea what I can do?

I appreciate any response!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go through this doc.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection

Answer (score -2):

I believe this would help:

```
db.collection('items').find({}, function (err, items) {
  var i = 0;
  items.each(function(err, item) {
    item.id = i++;
    db.collection('items').save(item, function (err) {});
  });
});
```

Please notice that it is Mongo DB Native NodeJS Driver syntax and methods like `each()` may vary